# How to handle locked orientation using React Native Stack Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I've an React Native Expo app running on both iOS and Android using Stack Navigation with two views. The first view is locked to portrait screen orientation

```js
export class HomeScreen extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.PORTRAIT_UP);
  }

  render() {...
  }
}
```

The second view should be available in both portrait and landscape screen orientation:

```js
export class DetailScreen extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(
      ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.ALL_BUT_UPSIDE_DOWN
    );
  }

  async componentWillUnmount() {
    await ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(
      ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.PORTRAIT_UP
    );
  }

  render() {...
  }
}
```

This is working almost as expected, but I have two issues:

1. When second view (`DetailScreen`) is in landscape and the back button is pressed, the first view (HomeScreen) is briefly shown in landscape orientation before rotation back to the portrait orientation. Is it possible to ensure that the device has rotated to portrait before navigating back? I tried doing that using `async await` in the `componentWillUnmount` method inside the `DetailScreen`, but the screen is still in landscape when the component is unmounted.

[image: HomeSceen is briefly shown in landscape orientation]

2. Using gestures I'm able to navigate back to the `HomeScreen`. But doing this gesture when the `DetailScreen` is shown in landscape, the `HomeScreen` is shown in landscape as well. How can I handle this? Is it possible somehow to disable this gesture inside the `DetailScreen` when in landscape orientation?

[image]

The example is available in this Expo Snack:
https://snack.expo.io/HJ_nhkQKH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated the expo snack for your question:
https://snack.expo.io/BJfXseXYB

Part 1. using NavigationEvents - onWillFocus

Part 2:

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(

  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: true,
      },
    },

    DetailView: {
      screen: DetailScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
      },
    },
  },

  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like the gestures to be enabled, but only disabled temporarily when inside the DetailedView and in Landscape. Is that possible?

Comment: Great solution with the ``onWillFocus`` event. I just changed to ``OnWillBlur`` and moved to the ``DetailView``, making the orientation stuff handled by the this special screen only. About part 2, I see that the navigationOptions can be set individually for each screen -- but can it be changed dynamically making me able to enable/disable when entering landscape mode in my ``DetailView``?

Comment: Thanks for your update, but the gestures is disabled in the ``DetailView`` both when the orientation is portrait and landscape. I would like it to be disabled only when the orientation is landscape. Is that possible?

Comment: I found a working solution based on this: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1274#issuecomment-334359018.

Comment: @dhrm I am seeing the same problem where I see an overlay of the screen while changing orientation. How did you fixed it? I am using React Navigation 5.x and react-native-orientation.